# How to commit from a downloaded (.zip) repository?

Tags: laravel, git

To deploy my Laravel app to my server, I decided to just download the zip file and unzip it in the folder.
However, I made some changes on my server and I would like to push them to GitHub. 
Since there is no .git folder, I don't get how am I supposed to commit the changes or pull from the repository.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Check out the Git repository. Replace the files in it with the .zip contents. Check `git status` shows something sensible, then commit and push. After you do all that, stop deploying via .zip and set up a proper Git-based deployment.

Comment: You can't. Don't use that method: clone the repository. (Use the GitHub forking mechanism first if needed, i.e., if you aren't allowed to push directly to that repository.) Grab your updated zip-file-based version from wherever you put it and put that into your new cloned repository, and start working with Git.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a repo already that has commits do:

```
git clone git@REPO_LOCATION_INFO
```

Check out a new branch on your local:

```
git checkout -b branch-name
```

Make your changes, save, add, commit, and push them:

```
git add .
git commit -m "My commit message"
git push origin branch-name
```

then open a pull/merge request in your repository and merge to master.

Otherwise you can remote the folder on your local to your repository with:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:user/repo_name
```

and then commit like shown above.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've successfully done that following way:

1. Rename repo zip downloaded (without .git)

`mv repo repo-bak`

2. Clone original repo

`git clone <url>`

3. move .git file to zip downloaded repo

`mv repo/.git repo-bak`

4. delete cloned repo

`rm -rf repo`

5. change the name back to the original

`mv repo-bak repo`

6. add, commit and do whatever you want

`cd repo && git status`